# Prepared statement WHERE ... IN (...) with array parameter

Tags: php, mysqli

In my case, I'm deleting from multiple tables using `LEFT JOIN` and need to provide an array of question ids to delete. The array of question ids is `$questions_to_delete`.

Not being able to bind an array as a parameter through `mysqli` is kind of a pain, and I've looked through a few SO questions to arrive at this:

```
$params = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($questions_to_delete), '?'));
$types = array_fill(0, count($questions_to_delete), 'i');
$delete_questions = $mysqli->prepare('DELETE    ...
                                          FROM questions
                                          LEFT JOIN ...
                                          WHERE questions.id IN ('.$params.')');

call_user_func_array(array(&$delete_questions, 'bind_param'), array_merge($types, $questions_to_delete));
$delete_questions->execute();
$delete_questions->close();
```

The error I'm getting is

**Warning**:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

I noticed that some answers used `&$delete_questions` versus `$delete_questions`, but I'm stumped as to what PHP is complaining about.

Comment: Should check a similar problem I faced on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864911/codeigniter-database-query-using-query-with-in-clause/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't merging `$types` and `$questions_to_delete` correctly! In my original code:

```
// Produces ['i', 'i', 'i', ...]
$types = array_fill(0, count($questions_to_delete), 'i');

// The argument (array_merge) is then ['i', 'i', ..., 'id1', 'id2', ...]
call_user_func_array(array($delete_questions, 'bind_param'), array_merge($types,$questions_to_delete));
```

What eventually worked for me was:

```
// Produces 'iii..'
$types = str_repeat('i', $questions_to_delete);

// The argument (array_merge) is then ['iii...', 'id1', 'id2', ...]
call_user_func_array(array($delete_questions, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($types),$questions_to_delete));
```

So the types of the parameters need to be a String at the beginning of the parameters array.

I don't really understand how `call_user_func_array` handles `array(mysqli_stmt, 'bind_param')` as a `callable`, or why the parameters have to be constructed this way, and I'd like to see if anyone can come up with an explanation!